# Node.js create a through stream that reads in file after receiving an end event

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'd like to create a stream for this kind of use-case:

```
foo()
.pipe(readFileIn('file.name'))
.pipe(bar());
```

`foo` is a function that that writes file to disk, and emits `"end"` once done. Once `foo`'s stream has finished, I need to read in that file from disk as a stream so I can `pipe` it onto the next handler.

How do I create a stream that does this?

Answer (score 0):

You can `pipe()` data to both `foo` and `bar`, as long as you `pipe()` before the `end` event. e.g.

```
var fs = require('fs');

var myDataSource = some.readable.stream();
var foo = fs.createWriteStream('foo.txt');
var bar = some.writable.stream();

foo.on('finish', function () {
  console.log('file written to disk');
});

myDataSource.pipe(foo);
myDataSource.pipe(bar);
```

Comment: I don't think this answers my use case. I'd like a through stream that I can pipe into and out of, that reads a file in only after I've received the first stream's `"end"` event. So, in my example above, I'm trying to figure out how to implement `readFileIn`

Comment: Sure, but why wait for the `finish` event?

Comment: Because the file I'm trying to read in doesn't exist until `foo` finishes

Comment: If `foo` is generating the contents of the file, you can `pipe()` those contents directly to `bar` while also `pipe()`ing them to a file on disk. I guess you need to clarify where the file contents come from.

Comment: So I don't have control of `foo`, it's just an API i'm using. It doesn't emit `"data"` events with the contents of the file, unfortunately, but it does emit an `"end"` event. All I know is when the file has been created, and where it got saved to.